# Difference between two timestamp in hh:mm:ss format

Tags: php

I have two timestamp like below format in my database.

```
$time1 = 4/19/2019 12:21:01 AM
$time2 = 4/19/2019 12:22:50 AM
```

I want get difference between this two timestamp like

```
12:21:01
```

Let me know if someone can give me idea/solution for do it using php.

Comment: there is no *one* difference. the second value has no date, so your difference could be any multiple of one day. unless you *assume* a date, what you want to achieve has no actual value. *if* you assume a date, just convert it to DateTime-objects and substract them.

Comment: I think You understood  it wrong, Let me edit my question. Thanks

Comment: @FranzGleichmann he has added the sample of timestamp and then he needs the output like the other.

Comment: I have edited my question for make it more clear. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the difference as

```
$time1 = '4/19/2019 12:21:01 AM';
$time2 = '4/19/2019 8:15:01 PM';

$start    = new DateTime($time1); 
$end      = new DateTime($time2); 
$diff     = $start->diff($end); 
print $diff->format("%H:%I:%S");
```

For more details [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Answer (score 2):

So you should have mysql select query like this:

`Select time1,time2,time_format(abs(timediff(time1,time2)), "%H:%i") as diff From table1`

You can change time format, follow this link for [time_format function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_time_format.asp)

Comment: This is using SQL whereas the question is about PHP.

Comment: He has mentioned that i have two timestamps in Database and i need difference.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can You please give me solution for PHP instead of SQL query? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the above answer by @Rakesh?